# Adverbial intensifier

Tags: vocabulary

Populi!

I try to find a word in Latin which couriers this specific sense:
*right, just, the very;*
and still found nothing.

I mean that I can find it in many another languages:
*right* here, *just* behind, in this *very* place;
*tam* artında;
*pryamo* za, *srazu* za;
they are very equal.

If I try to translate thus adverbs directly, they lose this tinge of the intensiveness.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll have to choose different words for precise meanings. One option is to use the intensifier *[ipse](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dipse)* (which is functionally what "very" is doing in your third example). The dictionary gives a good analogue to your examples:

> **ea** *enim* **ipsa hora** *acceperam tuas litteras*, "For it was **at this very hour** that I received your letter." (Cic. *Fam*. 7.23.4)

Another option is *[modo](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=modo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)*, which is used adverbially. You get phrases like *semel modo* ("only once"), *non/si modo* ("not only"/"not just", "if only"), and *nunc modo* ("just now"), though you don't even need the *nunc* to express that: it can mean "just now" by itself. Plautus *Rudens* 3.3.29 has "sedete hic modo* ("sit right here"), which matches your first example exactly.

Comment: Tnx! It seems that _ipse_ may be such intensifier. Waiting more answers.